# phpMyAdmin adds "key" to cross-table when adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a cross table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `a` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `b` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`b`),
  KEY `b` (`b`) # why?
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Why `phpMyAdmin` adds:

```
KEY `b` (`b`)
```

when I add foreign key in `Relational view` to `b` column?

Comment: Well, the foreign key needs to a **key** to reference...

Comment: So, foreign key for `a` column uses `PRIMARY KEY` and foreign key for `b` column uses `KEY`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. See [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for more info.

Comment: I understand this, but what I don't is why reference for `a` column uses `PRIMARY KEY` and column `b` creates another `KEY` when `b` is mentioned in `PRIMARY KEY` as well as `a`. Is it first column (`a`) of `PRIMARY KEY` some kind of "special"?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? I had a look at the current 4.0.5 version and the case of adding a self-referenced constraint to a column which is part of a multi-column index, is not supported. By the way, I don't think that it's phpMyAdmin who added the key on column b.

Comment: @MarcDelisle, 3.5.1. Week of research later and I still don't get it, why reference for column `a` uses `PRIMARY KEY` index and column `b` creates new one.